# What size should my image be to retrain Inception?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I am following 
[codelabs Tensorflow for poets](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#0) guide to re-train inception v3 with my own images. But there is no mention of what the size my image should be. I also watched some Youtube video that suggested cropping and filling in white spaces to make square images. But it didn't really mention the size.

How should I resize my training images to so I get the best result re-training inception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code prepares images for you and automatically and feeds them into the network. All you need to do is to properly setup the folders and provide enough training images. In my experience the size of images doesn't matter too much. I did retraining following the instructions using 640x480 and 1280x1024 images. I got great results with training sizes of 400 - 1000 images per class.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response.

Comment: Any idea what the script does though? What size of image does Inception v3 require, and how does the script take the input image and resize it to this size? also if you have 10,000 1mb images for training and it resizes them to 100k images can you pre resize them to this to save on your disk space?

Answer (score 6):

The code does the resizing for you. Have a look at [retrain.py](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2/blob/master/scripts/retrain.py). I have listed the code responsible for deciding the size of the images depending on the network architecture.

> ```
> if architecture == 'inception_v3':
>     # pylint: disable=line-too-long
>     data_url = 'http://download.tensorflow.org/models/image/imagenet/inception-2015-12-05.tgz'
>     # pylint: enable=line-too-long
>     bottleneck_tensor_name = 'pool_3/_reshape:0'
>     bottleneck_tensor_size = 2048
>     input_width = 299
>     input_height = 299
>     input_depth = 3
>     resized_input_tensor_name = 'Mul:0'
> ```